# Why if I run the build command I don't have a server created?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

There are two commands

```
 "dev": "webpack serve --hot --mode development --config ./configs/webpack.config.ts",
 "build": "webpack --mode production --config ./configs/webpack.config.ts",
```

When running in dev, I create a server. When I run build, a build is created for me.

Why is the localhost server not created when starting the build? if it is always specified to create? if I build on a real server, will the behavior be the same?

```
module.exports = (env: Server, argv: Imodul): Iwebpack => {

  let { mode } = argv;

  const isProduction: boolean = mode === 'production';
  const isDevelopment: boolean = mode === 'development';

  return {
    entry: {
      [MAIN]: ['./src/index.js'], 
    },

   
    devServer: {
      port: 3000,
      historyApiFallback: true, 
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see that you don't have the serve command in the build? You should look to this [serve](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#serve) command in webpack, it can help.

Comment: so I realized that if there is no this command, then the server will not be created?